# How to include Unity3d libs in a non-Unity3d project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm developing a C# library that will be used either as a plugin in some Unity3d projects and also used in non-Unity3d projects.

I need to use some Unity3d classes (such as UnityEngine.Matrix4x4) and standardize some functions to use valid types agnostically to whether the project is an Unity project or not.

So, as the title says: what is the right way to include Unity3d libraries in a non-Unity3d library project? Should I just include reference to the local Unity3d binaries (like UnityEngine.dll) in my project? If so, which is the right folder to look for these binaries (they appear in some different folders in the unity installation folder)?

Comment: I would not include them into your library since if you then use that library in a Unity project the types will be defined twice and you would get errors ... You could define these types yourself and use them according to your needs or do something like `#if UNITY_XY UnityTypes #else YourTypes #endif`

Comment: @derHugo rewriting unity binaries doesn't seem to be the right solution for my problem. There's got to be a more straight forward solution for this...

Comment: Well then you will have to rewrite it all instead of at least having Unity's source as start point ...

Comment: Another point against the Unity dll would be: you only want a maths library ... You don't want to include all Unity built-in types like `GameObject`, `Transform`, `Texture` etc .. I think it would help to know your actual use case ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not actually running the Unity Engine for rendering or handling input it may be the case of forcing a round peg into a square hole, both technically and legally.

The most elegant solution would likely be to write your library in C# using more agnostic libraries. For example the Matrix4x4 class you mentioned has an equivalent in [System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.matrix4x4?view=net-5.0). Alongside the library all thats needed is a light wrapper converting a System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 to a UnityEngine.Matrix4x4. Sometimes the Unity devs themselves do stuff like this, for example the [Unity.Mathematics.float3](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mathematics@0.0/api/Unity.Mathematics.float3.html) struct which works better in ECS land than a standard Vector3.

FYI if you're looking for how some particular system works, check out the C# Reference GitHub Repository, for example the [Matrix4x4 struct](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Matrix4x4.cs). Just be aware that 'copying and pasting' Unity source code is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

To include Unity3d libs in a non-Unity3d project, you will need to perform the following steps:

1. Obtain the Unity3d library files:

   - Locate the Unity3d installation folder on your computer.
   - Inside the Unity3d installation folder, find the "Editor" subfolder.
   - In the Editor folder, you will find the required Unity DLLs that you need to include in your non-Unity project.
2. Add Unity3d library files to your project:

   - Create a new folder within your non-Unity project where you want to store the Unity3d library files.
   - Copy the necessary Unity DLLs from the Unity3d installation folder into the newly created folder.
3. Configure your non-Unity project to reference the Unity3d library files:

   - In your non-Unity project, open your project settings or build configurations.
   - Look for an option to add references or libraries.
   - Add the Unity DLLs that you copied in step 2 to this list of references or libraries.
4. Configure project dependencies:

   - If your non-Unity project uses any Unity3d-specific functionality, like calling Unity APIs or using Unity-specific types, you will need to configure the dependencies correctly.
   - Ensure that the Unity DLLs are loaded and initialized in the correct order and sequence to enable the Unity functionality within your non-Unity project.

Keep in mind that including Unity3d libraries in a non-Unity project might not always be straightforward, as Unity3d relies on its own runtime and rendering environment. So, certain Unity-specific features or functionalities may not work seamlessly outside of the Unity environment.

Important Note: Please double-check the Unity3d licensing terms and conditions to ensure that including Unity3d libraries in a non-Unity project is allowed for your specific use case.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541